# How to integrate the Twitter widget into Reactjs?

Tags: twitter, widget, reactjs

I want to add the Twitter widget into React, but I don't know where to start or how to do it.  I am very new to React JS.

Here is the HTML version of the code:

```
<div class="Twitter">
  <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/<%= @artist.twitter %>" data-widget-id="424584924285239296" data-screen-name='<%= @artist.twitter %>'>Tweets by @<%= @artist.twitter %></a>
  <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>
```

And here is what I have so far:

```
React.DOM.div
  className: 'Twitter'
  children: [
    React.DOM.a
      className: 'twitter-timeline'
      href: "https://twitter.com/" + artist.twitter
      'data-widget-id': "424584924285239296" 
      'data-screen-name': artist.twitter
      children: 'Tweets by ' + artist.twitter
    React.DOM.script
      children: ...
  ]
```

I was planning to add the script where the dots (...) are, but that doesn't work.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You'll probably want to evaluate an alternate solution, but you can use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/special-non-dom-attributes.html) property in order to get the script to render properly

Comment: The `<script>` isn't pointing to an external resource (no `src` attribute). Could you copy the contents of the function in that script tag to your component and call the function in your component's `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 21):

First load Widget JS in your index.html(before your React scripts). Then in your component, simply do the following. The widget JS will rescan the DOM.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  twttr.widgets.load()
}
```

See: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization

Comment: Thank you for this, solved my problem that I was working on for a while.

Comment: From the twitter docs: "For better performance, pass an HTMLElement object to restrict the search only to children of the element.

Example:
```
twttr.widgets.load(
  document.getElementById("container")
);```

Comment: You may want to use componentDidUpdate instead if you are rendering dynamic nodes.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me!

Please note that I use React v0.14 and ECMAScript 2015 (aka ES6) with Babel.

index.html (after body tag):

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],  t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  t._e = []; t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };
  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

Twitter component:

```
const Twitter = () => (
  <a href="https://twitter.com/your-twitter-page"
    className="twitter-follow-button"
    data-show-count="false"
    data-show-screen-name="false"
  >
  </a>
);
```

Some React Component (that uses Twitter button):

```
class SomeReactComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Twitter />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or if you want to have a customized button, you can simply do this:

```
const Twitter = () => (
  <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=twitterdev">
    <i className="zmdi zmdi-twitter zmdi-hc-2x"></i>
  </a>
);
```

Comment: I found that with React 15.1.0, doing server side rendering, [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7093#issuecomment-229881089) happens.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be much easier to just use Twitter's `widgets.js`, more specifically [createTimeline](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/creating-widgets#create-timeline).

```
class TwitterTimeline extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    twttr.ready(() => {
      twttr.widgets.createTimeline(widgetId, this.refs.container)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref="container" />   
  }
}
```

You can load the library directly from `https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js`, but they recommend the following snippet:

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

More information on setting up the library is [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading).

Answer (score 3):

It's easy, all you need just use React's `componentDidMount` hook

```coffee
{createClass, DOM:{a}} = require "react"

@TwitterWidget = createClass
  componentDidMount: ->
    link = do @refs.link.getDOMNode
    unless @initialized
      @initialized = yes
      js = document.createElement "script"
      js.id = "twitter-wjs"
      js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
      link.parentNode.appendChild js

  render: ->
    {title, content, widget} = @props
    a
      ref: "link"
      className: "twitter-timeline"
      href: "https://twitter.com/#{widget.path}"
      "data-widget-id": widget.id,
      widget.title

TwitterWidget
  widget:
    id: "your-widget-id"
    title: "Your Twitts"
    path: "widget/path"
```

Comment: If you're using multiple widgets on the same page, this approach will create multiple script elements for each widget. For such cases you may want to use this approach: dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization For the example, it could be as simple as calling twttr.widgets.load(this.getDOMNode()); in componentDidMount(), provided widgets.js is already loaded

Comment: Showing this in normal JS instead of coffeescript or whatever language you're using would be more helpful.

Comment: Try this nice tool to translate above code into something more readable: http://js2.coffee/ (disclaimer: I'm not related to them in anyway, just found it useful)

Answer (score 3):

Try to install the **react-twitter-embed** by doing `npm install react-twitter-embed`. Once installed, the usage is pretty simple. Take a look at the screenshot below.

[image]

**Code Sample**:

```
import React from 'react';

import { TwitterTimelineEmbed } from 'react-twitter-embed';

const TwitterTimeLine = () => {

  return (
    <TwitterTimelineEmbed
      sourceType="profile"
      screenName="accimeesterlin" // change to your username
      options={{height: 1200}}
    />
  );
}

export default TwitterTimeLine;
```

They also have a list of other components that you can use as well.

List of available components

- **TwitterShareButton**
- **TwitterFollowButton**
- **TwitterHashtagButton**
- **TwitterMentionButton**
- **TwitterTweetEmbed**
- **TwitterMomentShare**
- **TwitterDMButton**
- **TwitterVideoEmbed**
- **TwitterOnAirButton**

Here is a link to the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitter-embed

Comment: Just to add additional information you can checkout storybook's docs section at https://saurabhnemade.github.io/react-twitter-embed/?path=/docs/twitter-timeline-embed--timeline-profile-with-screen-name which has show code where you will be able to get quick snippets with lots of examples!!

Comment: Hi @SaurabhNemade, I followed the same and it was working 7 days ago and it's now not working and only returns `<div></div>`. What would be the issue?

Comment: @usmanjutt84 Thanks for reporting. I'll take a look at this over the weekend. Apparently, a couple of parameters have been deprecated in the timeline.

Comment: @SaurabhNemade FYI, I notice that it's not working in the ReactJS APP while working in the storybook.

Comment: Another thing I also notice that `platform.twitter.com` is being blocked on my React website not only on my machine/network but globally.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should split it down in two.
A part of your code could be somehow rendered in a React component

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */
var React = require('react');
var twitterWidget = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div class="Twitter">
                <a class="twitter-timeline" 
                   href={this.props.link} 
                   data-widget-id={this.props.widgetId} 
                   data-screen-name={this.props.screenName} > 

                   Tweets by {this.props.screenName}
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
React.renderComponent(<twitterWidget link="..." widgetId="..." />, document.getElementById('containerId');
```

Your script tag could be placed, as a separate React component or as normal HTML just above the closing body tag.

Comment: Did you get this to work? Somehow when I try to combine the widgets.js and react things go wrong...

Answer (score 1):

```
class TwitterShareButton extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <a href="https://twitter.com/share" className="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        // scriptタグが埋め込まれた後にTwitterのaタグが置かれても機能が有効にならないので、すでにscriptタグが存在する場合は消す。
        var scriptNode = document.getElementById('twitter-wjs')
        if (scriptNode) {
          scriptNode.parentNode.removeChild(scriptNode)
        }

        // ボタン機能の初期化（オフィシャルのボタン生成ページで生成されるものと同じもの）
        !function(d,s,id){
          var js,
              fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
              p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
          if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
          }
        }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
      }
```

http://qiita.com/h_demon/items/95e638666f6bd479b47b

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [React Social Embed Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-social-embed).

<sup>*Disclaimer: It is a component created by me.*</sup>

Install by: `npm i react-social-embed`.

Usage:

```
import TweetEmbed from 'react-social-embed'

<TweetEmbed id='789107094247051264' />
/>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are few interesting solutions out there, but all of those are injecting twitters code to website.

What would I suggest is to create another **empty html file just for this widget**. Eg. `/twitter.html`, where you can place all dirty JavaScripts and render widget.

Then when you include:

```
<iframe src="/twitter.html" />
```

It will work without any issues. Plus, you have separated external scripts - so it's good for security.

Just add some styling to make it look fine:

*twitter.html*

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

*React's iframe*

```
iframe {
  border: none;
  height: ???px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I knows exactly where is the problem, first you need to understand how does react works.
React is frontend framework, works like all DOM is handled by react, if we directly integrate with DOM then sometimes it very difficult to code, cos React is also Updating that DOM.

As per the Twitter documentation, we cannot add twitter.js after init of web page.
https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization

so it better to use some package, **react-twitter-embed**

Simple step

```
npm install --save react-twitter-embed
```

```
import { TwitterTimelineEmbed } from 'react-twitter-embed';
<TwitterTimelineEmbed 
    sourceType="profile" 
    userId={"1029587508445630465"} 
    options={{height: 400}} 
/>
```

You can check other than timeline integration also using package.

https://romik-mk.medium.com/embed-twitter-timeline-widgets-reactjs-a27cafd7cfb6