# embed twitter timeline in react app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter

I am trying to add the English premier league twitter timeline to my react app. 
Twitter gives me the code snippet for HMTL which works in a regular HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>PREMIER LEAGUE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%40premierleague" data-widget-id="820173369198968833">Tweets about @premierleague</a>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to convert this into my react app but it does not work or throw any error. Here is code i used in react.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';





class App extends Component {

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h2>WELCOME TO THE PREMIER LEAGUE BLOG</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>PREMIER LEAGUE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href />
    <div>
      <a className="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%40premierleague" data-widget-id={820173369198968833}>Tweets about @premierleague</a>
      {!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");}
    </div>
  </div>

      </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: As your question was not clear and your question is near to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234101/how-to-integrate-the-twitter-widget-into-reactjs  cheers:)

Comment: Thanks @Codesingh. I'm still working on it.

Comment: Got it to work. Just needed to add the <a> tag to the body of my index.html component for the react app and the <script> tag in the head section.

Comment: that's pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

I had success using [react-twitter-embed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitter-embed)

```
<TwitterTimelineEmbed sourceType="profile" screenName="USERNAME" options={{height: 400}} />
```

But would need to trigger a re-render to get live updates.